# (version 5.13/5.14) Search Builder syntax error when "Groups" "is empty"

Tags: contacts, search-results, search-builder

in the latest versions of CiviCRM (5.13.4 and 5.14) we can no longer search for contacts that are not included in any group through the search builder!

First (at least until version 5.12) with this search:

[image]

we obtained "all contacts that did not belong to any group", while now we give a a **SINTAX ERROR**.

How to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a recent bug introduced by the fix to a different search issue, [issue #726](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/726).

A permanent fix will need to be found that doesn't break either scenario.  However, to resolve your immediate issue, you can open file `CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php` and delete [line 3037](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.14/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php#L3037).

I've reported this issue as [#1048](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1048).